# How do I obtain the machine epsilon in SAS?

Tags: sas

How do I obtain the machine epsilon in SAS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just googled it: http://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+obtain+the+machine+epsilon+in+SAS

First hit:

Use `CONSTANT('MACEPS')`.

Comment: since SO gets crawled in just few minutes now it's second hit :)

Comment: Haha, nice nice. I wonder how does SO do so well in Search Engine Optimisation...

Comment: It's now first! And I forgot the answer and I had to google it!

Answer (score 2):

This answer is sort of true.

However for doing calculations in the data step it is most likely 1*10^-12 because certain functions in SAS (eg log) round to this precision as part of their spec. I am  not sure about IML but I think that uses datastep functions. That could give a different result.